# Tsallis and Rényi Normalized Entropy

Tags: normalization, entropy

I'm working with Shannon, Tsallis and Rényi entropies.
I need to normalize these entropies for comparison purposes.
In Shannon's entropy you need only to divide by the log of the number of bins.

$$H(X) = -\sum_{i}\left({P(x_i) \log_b P(x_i)}\right)/\log_b(N)$$

where $N$ is the number of bins and $b$ the log-base (in Shannon is equal 2).

Edit:
Also for Rényi it is $\log(N)$

I'm missing Tsallis.

Comment: Shannon entropy has nothing to do with base 2. You can express it with any base (though for 2 you get bits as units; but many people use $e$, as it is easier for some calculations).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: "nothing to do with base 2" is perhaps misleading: as you say, base 2 is not compulsory but people in various fields regard it as standard or even most appropriate.

Comment: @NickCox Sure, base 2 is convenient and common. However, it seems that OP thinks that its a defining feature of Shannon entropy (vs other entropies).

Answer (score 2):

Tsallis and Rényi entropy is the same thing, up to some rescaling. All of them are functions of $\sum_i p_i^\alpha$, with the special case of $\alpha\to1$ giving Shannon entropy.

Look at [Tom Leinster's "Entropy, Diversity and Cardinality (Part 2)"](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2008/11/entropy_diversity_and_cardinal_1.html), especially at the table comparing these properties.

In short:

- Rényi entropies are in $[0, \log(N)]$,
- Tsallis entropies (called there $\alpha$-diversities) are in $[0, (1-N^{1-\alpha})/(1-\alpha)]$,
- $\alpha$-cardinalities are in $[1, N]$.

Also, one more way to go is to use:

- 1/cardinality, in $[\tfrac{1}{N}, 1]$,
- just $\sum_i p_i^\alpha$, in $[\tfrac{1}{N^{\alpha-1}}, 1]$.

The later two have the advantage that no matter what is the $N$, they always end up in $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by Piotr is mostly correct, but there is a tiny mistake.

The maximum Tsallis entropy value is actually given by the expression: $(1−N^{1−\alpha})/(\alpha-1)$.

The denominator order is reversed.

This is because this expression is obtained when dealing with a uniform probability distribution $ P = \{\frac{1}{N}, \frac{1}{N}, ..., \frac{1}{N}\}$

Considering the Tsallis entropy defined by the expression:

\begin{align}
      T &= \frac{1}{\alpha-1} \sum_{j=1}^{N}(P_{j} - (P_{j})^\alpha)\\
\end{align}

In this particular scenario, all instances of $ P_{j} $ will be equal to $\frac{1}{N}$. This means the sum can be reduced to $N\times(\frac{1}{N}-(\frac{1}{N})^\alpha)$. Therefore, we can rewrite this in the following way:

\begin{align}
      T_{\max} &= \frac{1}{α-1}\times\left \{N\times\left[\frac{1}{N}-\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^\alpha\right]\right\}\\
      T_{\max} &= \frac{1}{\alpha-1}\times (1-N^{1-\alpha})\\
      T_{\max} &= \frac{1−N^{1−\alpha}}{\alpha-1}\\
\end{align}

Comment: I don't have an opinion on whether or not this answer is correct, but this answer would be greatly improved if you could [edit] to show why this is correct. (BTW, nice profile pic -- I loved the first *Deus Ex* game.)

Comment: Edited to show the reasoning behind the final value. Also thanks, it's always nice to find people who played and liked this masterpiece.